# Forward declaration VS compiling order error in c++ to avoid recursive header inclusion

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I'm working on a large code in c++ composed by a lot of .h and .c files.

The main problem is caused by a pair of class wich are supposed to link each other.
Due to declaration need in the software architecture, the first class (name it A) is initializated in an "upper level" class.

so we got something like:

```
#include A.h
class mainClass{
...
A a;
...
}
```

A.h looks like:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include B.h
class A{
A();
fooA();
...
private:
B b;
...   
}
#endif
```

A.cpp looks like:

```
#include B.h
#include A.h
...
A::A(){
...
b(this) //here I get the first error that follows
...
}
A::fooA(){//do somthing}
```

In order to avoid mutual header inclusion in the second class (let it be B) I used forward declaration and a pointer var to class A.

B.h looks like:

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

class A; //Forward declaration to A
class B{
B()
B(A* const t)
fooB();
A* a;   //pointer to A object
}
```

B.cpp looks like:

```
#include B.h  

B::B(){
//default constructor. Do Nothing
}
B::B(A* const t){
  this->a=t //constructor that set the pointer to the object of type A
}

B::fooB(){
   a->fooA(); //here i get the second error that follows
}
```

Now if in my Makefile I link A before B i get the compiling error:

```
//First error. See code above for line numbers
error: no match for call to ‘(B) (A* const)’
```

On the other hand if I link B before A i get the compiling error:

```
//Second error. see code above for line numbers
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct A’
_B.h:'line of the forward declaration': error: forward declaration of ‘struct A’
```

I must admint i'm pretty new to c++ so I can't understand where I'm wrong.

**EDIT**

Now I'm using the solution:

1. use include guard
2. forward declare class A, and don't include A.h in B.h
3. include both B.h and A.h in A.cpp and B.cpp. Always include B.h before A.h

but I get the same error:

`error: no match for call to ‘(B) (A* const)'`

Could it be a constructor Overloading problem? If I remove the line

`b(this)`

The compiling works fine.

**SOLVED**

If a use an help function that set the variable A* a in B insted of using a constructor Everything works fine during compilation. Maybe I need to better understand constructor overloading in C++. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, the first thing that catches my eye: Your header files are missing include guards. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: I apologize for the mistake. All headers file yet have include guards...sorry again...I'm tryng to simplify the big amount of code in both the class and I forget to write the include guards in the code above.

Comment: I edited the post to better reflect the real status of my code.
Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use include guard
2. forward declare class A, and don't include A.h in B.h
3. include both B.h and A.h in A.cpp and B.cpp. Always include B.h before A.h

Comment: I tried this solution but I still get the "no match for call to" error. Seems the compiler can't find the constructor definition. I also included B.h in A.h, of course.

Comment: Are you writing:
    A::A() {
        b(this);
    } ? 
It should be:
    A::A()
        : b(this) {
    }; 

I have test your code, and it worked with mingw32-gcc 4.5.2

Answer (score 0):

Try including "A.h" from B.cpp!

That will resolve your "A" type when you need to use A from B.cpp.  Just make sure you don't do anything but keep a pointer/reference to A from within B.h, and do all real work with A from within B.cpp.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - follow 'us2012' idea and use include guards!

Then - change the forward declarations:

A.h:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
class B;
class A{
   A();
   fooA();
   ...
private:
   B b;
   ...   
}
#endif
```

and the include B.h in A.cpp

in B.h you include again A.h - but the include guards should prevent errors:

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "A.h"
class B{
  B()
  B(A* const t)
  fooB();
  A* a;   //pointer to A object
}
#endif
```

I haven't tested it ... but it should work.

Comment: But I believe that if a use a forward declaration to B in A.h I could use only pointer to B object, and I need to initialize the B object in A code. Am I wrong?

Comment: in the header you only declare the object - you only need to know the implementation in the *.cpp file - in this case when the contructor of A is called the first time. In A.cpp you can import B.h! But as I can see - you already found a solution!